# Unable to display all lines in the region-start in the PDF file

Tags: xslt, apache-fop

I have following XML as input

```
<AFPXMLFile>
  <docs>
    <regList>
     </regList>
     <regList>
        <region>2</region>
        <secList>
          <col>2</col>
          <lines>
             <line>IBM BELGIUM SPRL/BVBA </line>
             <line>d'entreprise/Ondernemingsnr TVA / BTW</line>
             <line>405 912 336/03.28.1.3 DISPENSE </line>
          </lines>
        </secList>
       </regList>
       <regList></regList>
       <regList></regList>
     </docs>
```

MY xsl for the start region as follows:

```
   <xsl:when test="region = '2'">
           <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-start">
                <xsl:for-each select="./secList/lines">
                    <xsl:for-each select="node()">
                    <fo:block-container reference-orientation="90" white-space="pre" font-size="4pt" color="green">
                    <fo:block>
                          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                          <fo:leader />
                    </fo:block>          
                    </fo:block-container>   
                    </xsl:for-each>
                 </xsl:for-each>
             </fo:static-content>    
        </xsl:when>
```

I my PDF file I see only the first line IBM BELGIUXxxx. I dont see the second and the third line. If I remove the orientation I see all three lines.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want stack `fo:block-container` from top to bottom, you should explicitly specify `@inline-progression-dimension` to each `fo:block-container`. Here is the sample XSL-FO.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
    <fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:simple-page-master master-name="spm" page-width="10.5in" page-height="10.5in">
            <fo:region-body margin-top="1in" margin-bottom="1in" margin-left="1in"
                margin-right="1in" overflow="error-if-overflow"/>
            <fo:region-before extent="1in" precedence="true" display-align="after"/>
            <fo:region-start extent="1in"/>
            <fo:region-end extent="1in"/>
        </fo:simple-page-master>
    </fo:layout-master-set>
    <fo:page-sequence master-reference="spm" reference-orientation="from-page-master-region()"
        writing-mode="from-page-master-region()">
        <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-before">
            <fo:block  border-bottom="1.5pt solid blue"/>
        </fo:static-content>
        <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-start">
            <fo:block-container reference-orientation="90" text-align="right" inline-progression-dimension="15em">
                <fo:block white-space="pre" font-size="9pt" color="green">IBM BELGIUM SPRL/BVBA</fo:block>
            </fo:block-container>
            <fo:block-container reference-orientation="90" text-align="right" inline-progression-dimension="15em">
                <fo:block white-space="pre" font-size="9pt" color="green">d'entreprise/Ondernemingsnr TVA / BTW</fo:block>
            </fo:block-container>
            <fo:block-container reference-orientation="90" text-align="right" inline-progression-dimension="15em">
                <fo:block white-space="pre" font-size="9pt" color="green">405 912 336/03.28.1.3 DISPENSE</fo:block>
            </fo:block-container>
        </fo:static-content>
        <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
            <fo:block font-size="1.2em" space-before="2mm" space-before.conditionality="retain">Region-start test</fo:block>
            <fo:block>Body text.</fo:block>
            <fo:block>Body text.</fo:block>
            <fo:block>Body text.</fo:block>
            <fo:block>Body text.</fo:block>
            <fo:block>Body text.</fo:block>
        </fo:flow>
    </fo:page-sequence>
</fo:root>
```

[Formatting result via FOP]

[image: Formatting result via FOP]

Or if you want to set up `<line>` elements from left to right, generate `fo:block-container` per `<lines>` element.

[Sample FO file]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
    <fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:simple-page-master master-name="spm" page-width="10.5in" page-height="10.5in">
            <fo:region-body margin-top="1in" margin-bottom="1in" margin-left="1in"
                margin-right="1in" overflow="error-if-overflow"/>
            <fo:region-before extent="1in" precedence="true" display-align="after"/>
            <fo:region-start extent="1in"/>
            <fo:region-end extent="1in"/>
        </fo:simple-page-master>
    </fo:layout-master-set>
    <fo:page-sequence master-reference="spm" reference-orientation="from-page-master-region()"
        writing-mode="from-page-master-region()">
        <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-before">
            <fo:block  border-bottom="1.5pt solid blue"/>
        </fo:static-content>
        <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-start">
            <fo:block-container reference-orientation="90" text-align="right">
                <fo:block white-space="pre" font-size="9pt" color="green">IBM BELGIUM SPRL/BVBA</fo:block>
                <fo:block white-space="pre" font-size="9pt" color="green">d'entreprise/Ondernemingsnr TVA / BTW</fo:block>
                <fo:block white-space="pre" font-size="9pt" color="green">405 912 336/03.28.1.3 DISPENSE</fo:block>
            </fo:block-container>
        </fo:static-content>
        <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
            <fo:block font-size="1.2em" space-before="2mm" space-before.conditionality="retain">Region-start test</fo:block>
            <fo:block>Body text.</fo:block>
            <fo:block>Body text.</fo:block>
            <fo:block>Body text.</fo:block>
            <fo:block>Body text.</fo:block>
            <fo:block>Body text.</fo:block>
        </fo:flow>
    </fo:page-sequence>
</fo:root>
```

[Formatting result via FOP]

[image]

Hope this helps your stylesheet development.

Comment: Thanks for responding to my question. I am sorry I forgot to mention that number of lines is dynamic, in one section it can be 3 lines, and in another section it can be 2 etc.

Comment: @Madhu If number of lines (or contents) vary per section, you should generate fo:page-sequence per section units. This enables generating fo:static-contents for fo:region-before separately.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This inline-progression-dimension="15em" attribute helped. I have all 3 lines displayed on the PDF file. Though it is not adding the line break between them. I will work on it.